# How to load HTML <object> SVG even when hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I need to wait for a certain object to load while it is hidden. But what appears to be happening, is that it only loads without the `display:none`;

I'm using jQuery, and I tried putting the `.load` on the object to call a function when it loads, but seems that it will not load, because it's hidden.

Is there a way of 'forcing' the load of the Object, or, another way to 'hide' but still loading?

How to do it correcly:

use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`

as explained here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#VisibilityProperty

> When the ‘display’ property is set to none, then the given element
>   does not become part of the rendering tree. With ‘visibility’ set to
>   hidden, however, processing occurs as if the element were part of the
>   rendering tree

Comment: Good question.  Now I'm curious as to the answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to doit correcly:

use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`

as explained here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#VisibilityProperty

> When the ‘display’ property is set to none, then the given element
>   does not become part of the rendering tree. With ‘visibility’ set to
>   hidden, however, processing occurs as if the element were part of the
>   rendering tree

thanks to @SomeKittens

Comment: Unfortunately, `visibility:hidden` is not enough to hide the svg on Chrome version 57. Even with width and height set to 0, there is still some spaces added. Using `display:none` works good.

Answer (score 3):

Load it off screen, `style="position:absolute;left:100000px"`

Comment: i thought in doing something like this, but is it thrustable?

Comment: @IvanSeidel I've seen it used but never used it myself

Comment: alternative - position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: -10000. (using it for opacity animation together with transition property)

Comment: The answer here will create a horizontal scroll bar, which is not ideal. @karlisup provides a better option. Combine with "width: 1em" to ensure the SVG will not cause a scrollbar even if it's big.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that an SVG [will not be rendered](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html) if the element is set to `display:none`.  It's possible to load every element individually with JS as shown in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3910130/1216976)